# TTrayIcon for MacOS?

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

In Windows VCL, I have the TTrayIcon to be able to (partially) hide my application. Is there a similar method to have an application being outside the normal task list on MacOS and only accessible in an alternate location normally reserved for background applications?

The specifics is a TCP/IP server listening on a port for incoming traffic, but one that doesn't need a UI interface (except for setup purposes). On Windows, I manage this with TTrayIcon and a TPopupMenu, but I am at a loss on how to implement similar functionality on MacOS.

Comment: Does MacOS support such functionality? (Does it support a notification area/task tray where you can *partially hide* applications?) What is it called on that OS?

Comment: From what I've seen on the net, it has a kind of System Tray in the upper right corner. But otherwise, what do background services do on MacOS if they want to run "silent" but still give the user access to them?

Comment: *From what I've seen on the net*? How are you writing MacOS applications without knowing anything about the OS?

Comment: That's an easy question. The answer is so simple: By using Delphi :-)

Comment: If you're after the macOS equivalent of a tray icon app, I have a component here: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/blob/master/Core/DW.StatusBarMenu.Mac.pas, and a corresponding demo: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/tree/master/Demos/macOSStatusBar. Note: It's a work in progress.

Comment: @DaveNottage: I ended up using your code, which works beautifully. Unfortunately, answers on StackOverflow cannot simply be links to off-site code or libraries, so I'm gonna Accept Olaf's answer, as he pointed me in the right direction. But many thanks for your comment (and code).

Comment: @HeartWare Which is why I posted it as a comment :-) Good to hear it works for you. Please feel free to use the issues page if you have trouble: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called *Menu Bar app* for Mac OSX. A search for "macos menu bar app source code" will yield lots of examples, but I have only found one (partial?) [example](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=108449) written in Delphi. The main API to use is [NSStatusItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstatusitem?language=objc).

EDIT: There is an example [statusitem.pas](https://sourceforge.net/p/lazarus-ccr/svn/369/tree//bindings/pascocoa/examples/statusitem/statusitem.pas) for Lazarus / Free Pascal which might be useful for your purposes.

Comment: Thank you - that looks like what I need. I'll test it when I get back at work and accept your answer if it indeed is what I'm looking for.